# Asking user to login to another website from within my app

Tags: login, security

I am working on an app which requires me to interact with an external API from an external website on behalf of the user. For this I need to ask them for their credentials for this other API. Will users refuse to login to the other website through my app due to security concerns? (Maybe that I would use their credentials for other malicious things).

I was thinking about performing the login through a Web View, this might make things look more natural for the user? Although I would prefer not using a Web View due to the platform I'm using to make the app does not support them very well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of using an external app to login is not new. Facebook, Google, Apple login, etc are a few examples that are already used wide spread. There is however a security concern. The examples mentioned are widely known and users are familiar with them which induces a level of trust. If the third party you are using is not known by your specific target users, mistrust can be an issue. Some work arounds:

1. Use copy to explain briefly and exactly what information you are using and for what purpose. Keep is short and truthful.
2. If possible, let the user choose what info to share. Give them control over their info.
3. Offer an alternative way to register. Letting them enter all their info manually. Might be more tedious for them, but not a big issue for security concerned individuals.

Comment: I like number 1 the most. But where should I show this infomation? In the terms & conditions of my application or somewhere else?

Comment: The content can be in the sign in screen, right before you ask them for their credentials.

Comment: From what I'm understanding, this is NOT what the OP it's talking about. This answer concerns OAuth (and similar). The question is about logging into a 3rd party API so it can be used by the app. Very different!